# Why can't i subscribe multiple times to a publisher?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

i wrote two methods,first one calls the publisher  (productDtoMono) only once and the other one calls it twice,
the first one returns bad request (empty body) when called from controller
while the second works perfectly and returns http ok
i did my homework and i see that i can't consume the publisher more than one time
why is that ?

```
public Mono<ProductDto> firstupdateProduct(Mono<ProductDto> productDtoMono) {
    return productDtoMono.flatMap(productDto ->
            productRepository.findById(productDto.getId())
                    .flatMap(p -> productDtoMono
                            .map(EntityDtoUtil::toEntity)))
                    .flatMap(productRepository::save)
                    .map(EntityDtoUtil::toDto);
}
public Mono<ProductDto> secondupdateProduct(String id, Mono<ProductDto> productDtoMono) {
    return productRepository.findById(id)
            .flatMap(product -> productDtoMono
                    .map(EntityDtoUtil::toEntity))
            .flatMap(productRepository::save)
            .map(EntityDtoUtil::toDto);
}
```

my controller method :

```
@PutMapping
public Mono<ResponseEntity<ProductDto>> updateProduct(@RequestBody Mono<ProductDto> productDtoMono){
    System.out.println("in controller "+productDtoMono);
    return productService.updateProduct(productDtoMono)
            .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
            .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());

}
```

Comment: `i did my homework and i see that i can't consume the publisher more than one time why is that` because you just wrote "consume" which is answering your question. Thats how it is designed, a `Mono` is a producer, it produces 0..1 items, and then its done. If you wish to consume it multiple times look into the `cache` function

Answer (score 0):

I did more research. Mono, Flux are cold publishers by default, so when the source of their creation comes from a request, they can only be consumed once. When we try to consume it a second time, it tries to generate the object from a request, hence the bad request get thrown. I had to cache the body while passing it to service like this:

```
@PutMapping
public Mono<ResponseEntity<ProductDto>> updateProduct(@RequestBody Mono<ProductDto> productDtoMono){
    System.out.println("in controller "+productDtoMono);
    return productService.updateProduct(productDtoMono.cache())
            .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
            .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());

}
```

and changed updateProduct like this

```
public Mono<ProductDto> updateProduct(Mono<ProductDto> productDtoMono) {
    return productDtoMono.map(ProductDto::getId)
            .flatMap(productRepository::findById)
            .flatMap(product -> productDtoMono.map(EntityDtoUtil::toEntity))
            .flatMap(productRepository::save)
            .map(EntityDtoUtil::toDto);
}
```

Comment: Cold means exactly the opposite of what you wrote. A cold publisher generates new data for each subscription.

Comment: it's exactly what i meant to write, "When we try to consume it a second time, it tries to generate the object from a request",it tries to generate data from a request, which is the source of your publisher, how am i wrong in that ?

Comment: _Mono, Flux are cold publishers by default, so when the source of their creation comes from a request, they can only be consumed once._ That statement insinuates that cold sources can only be consumed once (or requests are cold sources). That's not correct. Also, there is no default. In general, cold sources play no role in your situation, why mention them in the first place? Btw.: How many subscribers a stream can have does not depend on whether the source is hot or cold.

Comment: I said when the source that they generate data from is a request .. maybe I'm not getting your point idk